# Using TestStack.White.Uia3 with other TestStack.White packages

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests, white-framework

Currently using TestStack.White for a project, and ran across the Uia3 release on NuGet. However, can't seem to figure out if it's possible to use other packages (ex: TestStack.White.ScreenObjects) with this release, or if there are plans to release compatible builds.

The only real lead on the package is this [Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/teststack_white/49Kbk1BtxpQ) detailing the package. Based on my understanding, it seems to be a drop-in replacement for the mainline TestStack.White. But documentation is a little sparse. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the UIA3 build is a branch of the master branch so the TestStack.White.ScreenObjects should continue to work with it. The [UIAComWrapper](https://github.com/TestStack/White/tree/UIAComWrapper/src) branch is the UIA3 branch and has the ScreenObjects in it. It looks like the ScreenObjects was never published as a nuget package but it should be possible to use if someone publishes it.

Comment: Do you just have both NuGet packages (White and White.Uia3) installed side by side, then? Because the ScreenObject package depends on the mainline.

Comment: hmm looks like no one ever published a UIA3 ScreenObjects nuget package although it should be possible to do. I would open an issue for White and bring it up in their gitter channel some one should be able to generate that for you. Worst case scenario you could compile screen objects yourself and use it with the nuget package until some one can make the package.